# Strange error when uploading file - I think it is related to max file size

Tags: file-upload, php

I have a file upload script in PHP. The script works fine with smaller (under 2MB) but the larger files that need to be uploaded with this script (approx. 20MB) do not upload.

The script is below, then more explanation afterwards:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
 {
  $file = $_FILES["uploaddistance"]["name"];
  $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["uploaddistance"]["tmp_name"];

  $pathlevel3 = 'distance/level3/';
  $pathlevel4 = 'distance/level4/';
  $pathlevel5 = 'distance/level5/';
  $pathlevel6 = 'distance/level6/';


  $level = $_POST['distancecourse'];
  $module = $_POST['distancemodule'];
  $kaboom = explode(".", $file);
   $extension = end($kaboom);

  if ($level == "level3"){
   $pathandname = $pathlevel3 . $module . '.' . $extension;
   if (file_exists($pathandname)){
    unlink($pathandname);
    $moveresult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathandname);
   if ($moveresult == true){
   echo "Workbook uploaded";
    }
    }
   else {
    $moveresult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathandname);
    if ($moveresult == true){
     echo "Workbook uploaded";
     }
    }
   }

  else if ($level == "level4"){
   $pathandname = $pathlevel4 . $module . '.' . $extension;
   if (file_exists($pathandname)){
    unlink($pathandname);
    $moveresult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathandname);
   if ($moveresult == true){
   echo "Workbook uploaded";
    }
    }
   else {
    $moveresult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathandname);
    if ($moveresult == true){
     echo "Workbook uploaded";
     }
    }
   }

   else if ($level == "level5"){
   $pathandname = $pathlevel5 . $module . '.' . $extension;
   if (file_exists($pathandname)){
    unlink($pathandname);
    $moveresult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathandname);
   if ($moveresult == true){
   echo "Workbook uploaded";
    }
    }
   else {
    $moveresult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathandname);
    if ($moveresult == true){
     echo "Workbook uploaded";
     }
    }
   }

   else if ($level == "level6"){
   $pathandname = $pathlevel6 . $module . '.' . $extension;
   if (file_exists($pathandname)){
    unlink($pathandname);
    $moveresult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathandname);
   if ($moveresult == true){
   echo "Workbook uploaded";
     }
    }
   else {
    $moveresult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathandname);
    if ($moveresult == true){
     echo "Workbook uploaded";
     }
    }
   }   

   else {
    echo "Error 1";
    echo $level;
    echo $module;
    }

  }

 else {
  echo "error 2";
 }

?>
```

When I upload the larger files, the 'Error 1' message is appearing, suggesting that none of the POST values are being passed to the script. Like I said, this is not the case when uploading smaller files.

I've tried creating a custom php.ini file and altering max file sizes. I've made the following changes:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
memory_limit = 96M
```

The php.ini file is located in my home directory (public_html). As I understand it, this should automatically be used by any scripts within the directory. When I run a `phpinfo()` test on the site, it says that the loaded configuration file is public_html/php.ini (see http://www.xenonacademy.org.uk/phptest.php for details), which suggests that the configuration file is correct, but for some reason the problem still persists.

Also, when running this test it shows that `memory_limit` is only 64M, not the 96 that I specified in the php.ini, but the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` are correct. If these are set correctly, why is this not working? Do I need to `include()` my php.ini in relevant scripts or is there something more complex at work here?

Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Restart Apache/PHP?  The `upload_max_filesize` might need that in order to take.

Comment: Are you getting a memory limit error or is the script simply timing out?  Increase the max execution time.  What error are you getting?

Comment: The only error I'm getting is 'Error 1' which comes from my own error handling, so it looks like none of the POST data is getting passed to the script. This only happens on larger files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change these values with a "custom" php.ini, as it won't be usually read by webservers. Nether use `ini_set`, as [these directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads) are of the type [`PHP_INI_PERDIR`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php).

However, sometimes you can change them with `.htaccess` files and follow the instructions in the docs regarding [`MAX_FILE_SIZE`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) inputs:

> The MAX_FILE_SIZE hidden field (measured in bytes) must precede the file input field, and its value is the maximum filesize accepted by PHP. This form element should always be used as it saves users the trouble of waiting for a big file being transferred only to find that it was too large and the transfer failed.

Answer (score -1):

You ca use a before using file uploading function to override the php.ini file

```
 ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
 ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
 ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Comment: some of those can't be changed via `ini_set`... They effect things that happen before the code fires!  Look here at ['Changable column'](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)... PHP_INI_PERDIR.